# Not showing the submit variable in the url after form completed

Tags: forms

I have the following form, which works fine...

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="zip">ZIP: </label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" placeholder="ZIP Code" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="SEARCH">SEARCH</label>
<div class="col-md-4">

<input name="SEARCH" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SEARCH" formaction="zipsearch.php" formmethod="POST">
</div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

but the result becomes...

zipsearch.php?zip=ENTER_DATA_HERE&SEARCH=Submit

Is there a way that I can have the url only show the relevant variable I need, and not show the result of the submit button?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `name` attribute, it will not get passed through in GET/POST.